# MQTT Message properties

Tags: android, activemq-classic

We have a system which is already running, and we want to deploy android application to connect to our system. ActiveQ is used and each message properties comes from ActiveMQ contains very important information.
how I can read the message Properties 
I am using MQTT protocol and fusesource library

Answer (score 1):

MQTT Message don't have a properties section like some other protocols do.  You will need to encode everything you need into the message body as that is the only option with an MQTT message.

Comment: Is there any other protocol I can user for android that uses properties?

Comment: You could try and find a STOMP based library that works on android.